# Puppeteer adding jQuery with addScriptTag: "This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment"

Tags: puppeteer

I encountered this error when trying to inject a jQuery script into the browser with Puppeteer:

> This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment

when I use

```
await page.addScriptTag({url: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" });

await page.addScriptTag({ path: './jquery-3.2.1.min.js' });

await page.addScriptTag({ content: jquery });
```

Any idea on how to inject jQuery?

Comment: I think it's `await page.setBypassCSP(true)`

Comment: the comment above should be marked as a correct answer, it helped me also

Answer (score 0):

As [@pguardiario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966023/pguardiario) said, it would be:

```js
await page.setBypassCSP(true);
```

Take my word for it bros. It is the million-dollar line that I found in a tiny comment after hours of trying different methods of solving this and searching the web extensively. Sigh. Sometimes simple stuff is hard to figure out.